# Map file analysis

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, c++

I have been writing a software for an embedded controller in C++. I have noticed
that I have some problems with ram memory (I have probably run out of the 
available memory). I have decided to inspect a map file but I have found that
I am not able to find several queues in the map file. These queues are defined
as private attributes of some object in my source code. Does anybody know why 
the private attributes aren't visible in the map file? Thank you for
any ideas.

Comment: Mapfiles likely look different depending on which toolchain you use. Can you paste an example map file or give a hint on which toolchain you are using?

Comment: How can we possibly answer such a specific question with no detailed information about what you're doing: What microcontroller? What toolchain? What source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that "automatic variables" in C don't persist outside of individual invocations of a subroutine, and are usually dynamically allocated on the stack.  Those therefore don't show up in a map file since they don't exist at that level.

They do, however, consume stack space.  You have to make sure the amount of memory available to the stack is enough for the worst case nesting of subroutines that will ever occur in your project.  That can be difficult to know.  Some development suites have tools to help with that.

One trick to get some idea of stack usage is to load the whole stack area with a specific data pattern.  Let the system run while you hopefully exercise every case.  Then look at the stack area with a debugger and see how deep it got by finding where the original pattern was overwritten.  Note that this only shows you how deep the stack got during the test, not how deep it could get.  This method depends on how well you exercised the system during the test.

Some processors, like the PIC 24 and dsPIC series from Microchip, have a means for hardware to detect a write near the end of the stack.  This is done with the stack limit register.  A trap is generated if stack data is written past the limit.

### Added about "queues"

As Dave Tweed pointed out in a comment, something called a "queue" may not be allocated dynamically on the stack.  In that case, it does permanently reside in memory.

However, some toolchains lump together all private but statically allocated memory of a module as one number in the map file.  Actually, this would be per module per *section*, but normally all such memory would be in a single section unless you went out of your way to define it otherwise.

If your toolchain does this, there are several options for making the size of specific private variables spelled out in the linker file:

Declare the variable to be in a special section.  All toolchains I've seen will show you sizes of statically allocated sections one way or another.

Declare the variable global.  This is bad software practice if the variable is only access inside the module, so you do this temporarily only to see the result in the map file.

Some systems have a setting that causes private but statically allocated variables to be shown individually in the map file.

Comment: It's rather unlikely that something containing a "queue" would be an automatic variable. But since the OP gave us no details about what he's doing, there's no way to be sure.

Comment: @Dave: Agreed. See addition to answer.

Comment: Also stuff allocated dynamically with malloc/new won't appear in a map file.

Answer (score 0):

Compositions show up in different places than you might expect. The visibility defined in the code has no effect on that. Private data shows up in the link file just like any other data.

We have a static system build (no dynamic memory management) so in the map file, all RAM is allocated by the "mother" object which has all the compositions to the other objects.

The classes get their own code usage, but no RAM usage except for static variables.

The total RAM usage is usually given correctly, finding out which object uses how much RAM is a bit tricky. I've used the Lauterbach Debugger tools for that in the past which is able to generate a map of the RAM usage to the objects.